# if $a,b,c$ are the roots of the equation $x^3-px^2+qx-r=0$ find the value of $(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $a,b,c$ are the roots of the equation $x^3-px^2+qx-r=0$ find the value of $(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$

Using vieta's formula:

$a+b+c=p$

$ab + ac +bc = q$

$abc = r$

on expansion of the bracket,

$(b+c)(c+a)(a+b) $

$=(bc+c^2+ab+ac)(a+b)$
$=(q+c^2)(a+b)$
after this step I am unable to proceed further. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Hint: the expression becomes $(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)$ which is just the cubic evaluated at $p$.

Comment: @Sahaj Thank you, that solves the problem. After factorization it becomes
$-r + p(ab+ac+bc)-p^2(a+b+c)+p^3$

Answer (score 3):

Since $a,b,c$ is the solutions, we have
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=0=x^3-px^2+qx-r,$$
and let $x=a+b+c$, we have
$$(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)=(a+b+c-a)(a+b+c-b)(a+b+c-c)\\=(a+b+c)^3-p(a+b+c)^2+q(a+b+c)-r$$

Comment: Well, you may want to set $x=p$ instead, to get $pq-r$.